# Creating Spree Extension

Tags: spree

Hey I have tried a lot creating spree extension , but after weeks efforts also I am not getting the desired outcome out of it. I have followed the **spreecommerce** website on extension tutorial but I didn't found it enough  for a spree beginner.

Please suggest some good spree tutorial links.

Its urgent!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply in terminal in the dir of the spree store.

```
spree extension <nameofextension>
```

Comment: This was also really helpful. http://speakerdeck.com/u/jsqu99/p/spreeconf-2012-introducing-spree-10

Answer (score 0):

http://www.theroamingcoder.com/?q=node/11

http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/01/rails-ecommerce-spree-hooks-tutorial.html
see also [Spree, Rails 3, and theming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952300/spree-rails-3-and-theming)

http://www.spreecamps.com/devcamps-tutorial